# How do I change django's default sqlite3 database to a more advanced one like MySQL?

Tags: django, database

I want to use a better database with my Django like **postgresql** or **mysql**. what are the steps in doing that?

Comment: You need to make these dbs manually first and input their settings in your application's settings.py like so: DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'mydb',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'mysql',
        'PORT': '3306'
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

In case of MySQL:

1. Install `mysqlclient` in your virtualenv.

```
$ pip install mysqlclient
```

2. Enter MySQL and Create database to connect your project

```
$ mysql
mysql> create database django_project;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> use django_project
mysql> show tables;
Empty set (0.01 sec)
```

3. Connect your project to database(MySQL)

```
# your_settings.py

...
DATABASES = {
    'default' : {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',    
        'NAME': 'django_project',                
        'USER': 'root',                          
        'PASSWORD': 'password',                  
        'HOST': 'localhost',                     
        'PORT': '3306',                          
    }
}
```

4. Migrate

```
$ python manage.py migrate
```

5. Check

```
$ mysql
mysql> use django_project;
mysql> show tables;
+--------------------------+
| Tables_in_django_project |
+--------------------------+
| accounts                 |
| comments                 |
| django_content_type      |
| django_migrations        |
| django_session           |
+--------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

6. Done!